# Scrapy CSS/XPath Selectors

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I am trying to capture the text of a number of HTML elements on [this page](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/carb-manager-keto-diet-app/id410089731#see-all/reviews) examples below:

`<p dir="ltr" data-test-bidi="">I’ve really loved using this app...</p>`

`<time data-test-customer-review-date="" datetime="2019-07-21T22:32:44.000Z" aria-label="July 21, 2019" class="we-customer-review__date">07/21/2019</time>`

I have tried several different selectors:

`response.xpath('//time[@class="we-customer-review__date"]/text()')`

`response.css('p').attrib['dir']` <- this returns an error

`response.xpath('//p/text()').getall()` returns all the `<p>` elements but i cant filter through to ones I want. Any suggestions?

Comment: _this returns an error_ What error? _but i cant filter through to ones I want._ What does that mean? Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message, and see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
ptags = response.css('p') #selects all the p tabs
texts =[]
for ptag in ptags:
    if ptag.css('p::attr(dir)').get() is not None: #selects the ones that have dir prop
         text = ptag.css('p::text').get() #extracts the text
         texts.append(text) #append to the list or whatever
```